# jQuery AJAX call with browser authentication

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication

I want to send an AJAX request using jQuery.
Calling the url requires an authorization. Typing the URL directly in the browser, the browser's authorization/login dialog pops up.
How can I use this credentials or force the dialog to pop up using jQuery?

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "myURL",
    data: {  param1: "1"},   
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){    
     console.log( data );  
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){    
      console.log( errorThrown );  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Render your same page whenever authentication fails inside iframe.**

```
var url = "your website url here"

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "myURL",
    data: {  param1: "1"},      
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',    
    success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){       
      console.log( data );    
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){        
      if(jqXhr.status==401){           
          $('<iframe src="'+url+'"></iframe>').appendTo('body');          
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: But for this, I need the username and password. How can I get this from the default browser's dialog (and prevent writing my own login page)?

Comment: I didnt get your question. Can u clarify properly?

Comment: Calling an URL where authorization is required in the browser, the browsers ask for authentication using its default authentication dialog ... e.g. if a site is secured via .htaccess. ... I want to use this credentials for my ajax calls ... and I don't want to prompt/ask the user again (and with my own login page) for his credentials.

Comment: Nice idea :-) ... but I got: "Load denied by X-Frame-Options: ... does not permit cross-origin framing" ... is there no way to access/reuse the entered credentials from the browser for this site?

Comment: Its server issue.The page which you are rendering inside iframe is restricted by server.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe      go to this and check by changing src to www.google.com or any other.You will face same error as server dont want their content to be shown as a subpage of other website.

Comment: It will work if your ajax origin and url you are requesting are same.